# java.net.UnknownHostException:in Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I have started a sample jsoup program but there is an error as UnknownHostException.The code written is

[image: 1]

and the error is : 
 [image: 2]

please help me on this.

Comment: Please do not link to screenshots of code. Put the code in textual form in your question. This makes the question easier to read. The same applies for the error message.

Comment: ok sure..
can u pls help me on this

Comment: I was just trying to advice you on improving your question. Maybe it helps if you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good questions are more likely to get answered. :)

Comment: add images to question

Comment: thanks for editing the question. From next time i will post questions like this

Comment: Did you try to google your error? The first result gets you to java docs - **Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.** The next results are from SO users who had the very same problem. Maybe one of those links can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your DNS relsolution is not working correctly. You can see from the first line in the Exception, which points somehow to "www.realself.com", which is not google I think.

So this is likely not a JSoup problem, but a problem of (Java) networking. Can you try to access the page in a normal browser?

P.S. You should do as the comments suggest and include the stack trace in text form, not as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also check your Internet connection